# Magento2: Default success messages not showing at frontend

Tags: magento2, messages

I've installed magento version 2.1.1 and facing issues that Magento's default success/failure messages not showing at frontend on top of the page.

**Example** 
**1.** If I add product to cart it doesn't show success message for adding product to cart however product is added to the cart.

**2.** I'm submitting contact us form, receiving email but success message not showing at top.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: I'm seeing this error in firebug "ReferenceError: cookieMessages is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out this issue and fixed it.

I had created a custom theme on magento version 2.0 and overridden few default templates/js files of core Luma theme.

After few days, that instance was corrupted and hence I've installed latest Magento version i.e. 2.1.1 and used my custom theme there. Everything working fine except this issue. So I looked into it and found that Magento Team has done some changes in core templates/js etc.
Then I found the culprit is messages.js at app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme_name\Magento_Theme\web\js\view. I've replaced that file, deployed content and Magento showing success/failure messages now.

Hope someone may help this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide full path 
app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme_name\Magento_Theme\web\js\view ??